# Color all tasks from the same person

Tags: angular

I have various tasks assigned to one person. For example, if I click on Max's task, then all of Max's tasks should be highlighted in color. It is currently the case that only the task is highlighted in color that was clicked on.

How can I make it so that when I click on a task, all tasks are marked by the same person?

This is the complete code:

import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styles: [
    `
      .task-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        column-gap: 10px;
      }
      .task {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        row-gap: 5px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        padding: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    `,
  ],
  template: ` <div class="task-wrapper">
    <div
      *ngFor="let task of tasks"
      class="task"
      #highlightTask
      (click)="highlightTasks(highlightTask, task.name)"
    >
      <div>{{ task.name }}</div>
      <div>{{ task.task }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  tasks = [
    { name: 'Max', task: 'Task 1' },
    { name: 'David', task: 'Task 2' },
    { name: 'Max', task: 'Task 3' },
    { name: 'David', task: 'Task 4' },
  ];

  @ViewChild('highlightTask') highlight: ElementRef;
  public highlightTasks(element: HTMLDivElement, taskOwner: string) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the directive ngClass to apply a css class based on a condition.

Whenever you click a task you store the clicked task's name.

On ngClass you will add the "task-highlighted" css class if the clicked task's name matches with the rendered task's name. Here is the code

```
  @Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  styles: [`
      .task-highlighted {
        color: red;
      }
      .task-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        column-gap: 10px;
      }

      .task {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        row-gap: 5px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        padding: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    `,
  ],
  template: ` <div class="task-wrapper">
    <div
      *ngFor="let task of tasks"
      class="task"
      #highlightTask
      [ngClass]="{'task-highlighted': clickedTask == task.name}"
      (click)="highlightTasks(task)"
    >
      <div>{{ task.name }}</div>
      <div>{{ task.task }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  clickedTask: string = '';

  tasks = [
    { name: 'Max', task: 'Task 1' },
    { name: 'David', task: 'Task 2' },
    { name: 'Max', task: 'Task 3' },
    { name: 'David', task: 'Task 4' },
  ];

  highlightTasks(task: any): void {
    this.clickedTask = <string> task.name;
  }
}
```